# deletion confirmation

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactionsheet, confirmation

I have one UIAction Sheet and there are 4 buttons, 1 is delete.
delete is running perfectly but now i want to add some confirmation box, so if user click on "Yes" button the record will be delete else not.
I don't know how to add this confirmation box and where?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@pooja i suggest u to use `UIAlertView` for that in your code where you are using `UIActionSheet` delete button on delete button  action call this..

```
UIAlertView *updateAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Item Deletion" message: @"Do u really want to delete" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"YES"  otherButtonTitles:@"NO",nil];

    [updateAlert show];
    [updateAlert release];

}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==0)
    {
    //give deletion code here   
    }

}
```

and do forgot to call `UIActionSheetDelegate`...
Hope this will help u!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an alert view for this purpose.When the button at index 0,1 is pressed perform the desired action.You will have to put this alert view when the user presses the delete button of the Action Sheet.

Cheers